# Detect if it is a new user or not in PHP

Tags: craft3, php, registration

I have been developing some plugin code for my registration form in Craft 3.

The event will be `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT`, but I do not know how to detect if it is a new user or not.
In Craft 2, the way was `if ($event->params['isNewUser'])`.

It would be grateful for me if someone tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Craft 3 you would do:

```
Event::on(
    Elements::class, 
    Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT,
    function(Event $event) {
        if ($event->element instanceof \craft\elements\User && $event->isNew) {
            // It's a new user 
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Yes, your code works well. Thank you.

Comment: Thankfully I found this one my second search, works perfect!